# How to get the longitude and latitude values using google API?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, microstrategy

I am trying to integrate a custom d3 visualisation into MSTR. For testing purpose, I am trying to pull the longitude and latitude values using google API's. But the issue which I am getting is that I am not able to get the values for more than 12 values. Here is the sample code
var rawD = this.dataInterface.getRawData(mstrmojo.models.template.DataInterface.ENUM_RAW_DATA_FORMAT.ADV);

var rawD = this.dataInterface.getRawData(mstrmojo.models.template.DataInterface.ENUM_RAW_DATA_FORMAT.ADV);

```
var someData = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < rawD.children.length; i++) {

  someData.push({
  country: rawD.children[i].name,
    value: rawD.children[i].value

  });

  }

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var len=rawD.children.length;

for(i=0;i<len;i++)
  {

var address = someData[i].country;

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    alert(longitude);
  } 
}); 

  }
```

Could someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: *"not able to get the values for more than 12 .."* doesn't really explain a detailed problem or what happens beyond 12

Comment: @charlietfl  When I use the above code. It returns only 12 longitudes and latitudes values for the regions(regions containing 51 values). So, it should return 51 longitudes and latitudes values. I am using an alert to see the values for longitude and latitude but it only returns 12 values initially and then alert doesn't show up and then when I run it again it only returns 5 long and lat values and on the next test, it doesn't return anything. So, I am not sure what is wrong with the code.

Comment: note that geocoder service has use limits. Should geocode the locations once and store the coordinates where you store the addresses

Comment: @charlietfl I am not getting a clear picture in what you're trying to explain. can you explain in detail?

Comment: read the google geocoder use limits docs